# Divide Vector into chunks with constant memory

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

suppose you need to work with great amount of elements (1 bilion+) that are stored in vector and at one moment, you would like to take all of these elements and divide them into groups. To be specific, we would like to do following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> groups(100, std::vector<int>);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    groups[i % 100].push_back(big_vector.push_back(i));
}
big_vector.resize(0);
big_vector.shrink_to_fit();
```

However, since `big_vector` is really massive, it is quite inconvenient to have our data in memory duplicated. This however probably can not be avoided due to vectors continuous memory allocation and inability to resize itself without copying the whole data (Correct me if I am wrong).

The question is then, what other structure to use to store our big data? I thought of writing custom container, that would internally store data in `std::vector<std::array<SIZE>>`, where `SIZE` is sufficiently large not to have too many chunks, but not that big to cause problems with duplicate memory overhead. Is there more standard-ish (boost-ish) way of doing this, or is writing custom container my best bet?

To further specify my expectations of the container - it would be nice if it had interface similar to vector (fast random access etc.). However if necessary I would probably could get by without random access and only the ability to push and read things. This though has to be very fast anyway.

Comment: "*However if necessary I would probably could get by without random access and only the ability to push and read things.*" How about `std::unordered_set<>`/`std::unordered_multiset<>`? In C++17 they gain [`extract`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/extract) and [`merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/merge) member functions that do what you want.

Comment: The function which you use to divide elements in groups is `f:i->(i%100)` i.e given an index `i` it will go to group `i%100`. So do you really need groups. You can find the group on demand. Also `vector::push_back()` do not return any value, so this is incorrect `groups[i % 100].push_back(big_vector.push_back(i));`

Comment: ah, I should have been more specific about that. I in real code they are divided into groups by more sophisticated rules and it is necessary to have them in separated vectors. On topic of `std::unordered_set` -  wouldn't it introduce big memory overhead? I am not really familiar with implementation of unordered sets.

Comment: `std::unordered_xxx<>` are node-based, which has overhead; but that's also what allows them to transfer elements without duplicating them. It's up to you whether or not it's worth the tradeoffs.

Comment: So, can't you have the big data already sorted by group? Or just do sort(big_data, group_comparator)? This will cost (n*logn) time, but only additional logn memory (with most of the `std::sort` implementations?).

Comment: Maybe openmp parallel and workshare concepts may be useful? There are a lot of links in google: http://phoenix.goucher.edu/~kelliher/s2012/cs325/workshare1.c